# How can we pass dynamic values in pie chart in jqplot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot, pie-chart

How can I have dynamic values in pie chart,

[image]

i.e. I want to have "Heavy Industry",12 and so on dynamically.

Comment: Where does your dynamic data come from ? Which format ? ... The data format for the plugin is just an array which contains couple of key value.

Comment: @advait : we cannot read your mind, so please provide more information on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand correctly your question. But you just need to create the data array dynamically.

```
var data= new Array();
for(var elem in tab)
   data.push([elem.key,elem.value]);
   //assuming tab is an array filled with object  with attributes key and value
```

And then

```
jQuery.jqplot("chartname",[data]....
```